# Copying array contents from one to another ( dynamic memory allocation)

Tags: c

In the code which I have pasted below, after I copy the contents of split data i,e "he", "ll" and "oo" to new data array (which is 2d array) . I am freeing the StringSplit[i]. But after freeing, i am not able to see the data which i copied to 2d array newData also. what is happening in this code and how do i ensure the data in varible "newData" is saved. and newData is global variable

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    char *data= "Helloo";
    StringOperations(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that 1. `malloc(const_length)` allocates too little memory. 2. If it's really const length, you should not use `malloc()` because it's slower and because it's harder to then `free()` all the `malloc()`ed pointers at the right time.

Comment: There is no  2D array in your code and nothing which can point to one. `char **` is a pointer to pointer, a pointer is not an array.

Comment: What is your **specific** question? We are not an "explain/write" my code site.

Comment: Well I closed as duplicate to "how to copy strings", but upon closer inspection this code has _lots_ of other major problems. Basically, you need to actually know what you are doing, you can't program by "take a chance" trial & error.

Comment: @Lundin people learn this way, but they use debuggers, try and test their ideas -and they do not write posts on the forums with questions which can be answered by stepping through the code

Comment: @PeterJ_01 "they do not write posts on the forums with questions which can be answered by stepping through the code" I take it you are being sarcastic? Because questions without any debug effort by the OP what-so-ever are _quite_ common around here...

Comment: @Lundin I think that my intentions are obvious ... :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 serious problems with your code,

1. There is always one more byte for a string in [c](/questions/tagged/c) so, you should have

   ```
   int const_length = 3;
   ```
2. You `free()` `StringSplit[i]` and then dereference the pointer you assigned to it previously. Pointers are just that, they point to memory. Assigning a pointer to another does not create new memory and you dereference exactly the same poitner you just `free()`ed.
3. Not so serious, but you should check if `malloc()` returns a valid non-`NULL` pointer.
4. Not serious at all, but casting the return value of `malloc()` [is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495).

Comment: How to do fix this issue.. can you give me example. I did not understand how to solve it :(

Comment: If you need to use the pointer don't `free()` it, use `free()` exactly when you NO LONGER NEED THE DATA.

Comment: If I want to free the StringSplit[i]  in a different function for example​.. how do I free it? Because I won't have variable 'i' in new function as it local variable..

Answer (score -1):

```
newData[j]=StringSplit[i];
```

`newData[j]` is pointing where `StringSplit[i]` is. So effectively you are freeing memory where both are pointing.

Comment: @Downvoter Its good if you please mention the reason too. I'm confused what I said wrong.

Comment: It's correct, but difficult to understand. And if you read the code you'd know that there is something else that's causing UB.

Comment: Lot of issues are there but OP is asking exactly this question. Could you please tell whats difficult to understand.